# how get only 'unique' sub-subdocument in mongoose, removing the duplicates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i'm new to mongodb & mongoose, the more i search in the mongoose documentation, the more i get lost.
say i have a `user` which it's `name` field has the value **John**, John have two `role`s:

- Superuser
- Admin

each one of this `role`s has some `permissions`:

- Superuser

  - addQuestion
  - editQuestion
  - removeQuestion
- Admin

  - addQuestion
  - viewAnswer

as you see there are duplicates for each `role`, how can i get the permissions of user **John** in an array without duplicates(the repeated one in this example is `addQuestion`), like this:

['addQuestion', 'editQuestion', 'removeQuestion', 'viewAnswer']

this is my Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate')(mongoose);

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    user_roles: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Role'
    }]
});

var RoleSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    permissions: [
        {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Permission'
        }
    ]
});

var PermissionSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});


UserSchema.plugin(deepPopulate, {
    whitelist: ['user_roles.permissions']
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema),
Role   = mongoose.model('Role', RoleSchema),
Permission = mongoose.model('Permission', PermissionSchema);
```

as you see i don't have the permissions names in the `permissions` array, i have references(`ObjectId`s).

i only have a `userId` came from the url.
so:

```
User.findById(userId)
    .deepPopulate('user_roles')  
    .deepPopulate('user_roles.permissions') 
    .distinct('permissions') 
    .distinct('user_roles.permissions') 
    .exec((err, user)=> {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        ????
        res.json(permissionsArr);
    });
```

should i use `distinct` ?
can i use `distinct` without `populate`ing first? or is it a must?
or instead of `distinct` i should use the `user` item passed in to the callback and instead of the `????` use the `user` parameter(using the `find` method) to get all the roles, and for all roles get the permissions, and then removing the duplicates out of the `permissionsArr` array?

UPDATE: this is the result of a rest api i made using mongoose, getting user roles(GET http://localhost/api/users/:userId/roles):

```
app.get('/api/users/:userId/roles', function(req,res) {
    User.findById( req.params.userId )
        .deepPopulate('user_roles.permissions')
        .select('user_roles')
        .exec((err, users)=> {
            if(err) next(err);
            res.json(users);
        });
}
```

the result:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "_id": "56e677c1a7e7007d5cc245ef",
  "user_roles": [
      {
          "_id": "56e64f057e8008263dec2cc9",
          "name": "superuser",
          "permissions": [
              {
                  "name": "removeQuestion",
                  "_id": "56e408a9d863a8cf4d7ab001"
              },
              {
                  "name": "addQuestion",
                  "_id": "56e64d657e8008263dec2cc4"
             },
             {
                  "name": "addAnswer",
                  "_id": "56e64cf87e8008263dec2cc3"
             },
             {
                  "name": "viewQuestion",
                  "_id": "56e64e1e7e8008263dec2cc5"
             },
             {
                  "name": "viewAnswer",
                  "_id": "56e64e267e8008263dec2cc6"
             }
          ]
    },
    {
          "_id": "56e64ec27e8008263dec2cc8",
          "name": "admin",
          "permissions": [ 
              {
                  "name": "addQuestion",
                  "_id": "56e64d657e8008263dec2cc4"
              },
              {
                  "name": "addAnswer",
                  "_id": "56e64cf87e8008263dec2cc3"
              },
              {
                  "name": "viewQuestion",
                  "_id": "56e64e1e7e8008263dec2cc5"
              },
              {
                  "name": "viewAnswer",
                  "_id": "56e64e267e8008263dec2cc6"
              }
          ]
        }
```

now what i need is to `GET` http://localhost/api/users/:userId/permissions and by that getting the `permissions` of the `roles` that the user has, but with the duplicates been removed.(`user` should not have `permissions` directly.)

thank you for your time and for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: I'd suggest you to update your post with sample documents with duplications from MongoDB.

Comment: i don't know how to populate after querying in mongodb shell, but i provided the JSON coming back from my rest api containing the duplicates. would be really nice if you give a hint @Saleem. thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing some codes with your schema, I find the `.distinct` just distinct the value of `user_roles` rather than the result of `populate`, such as `user_roles.permissions`. Here maybe one way to remove duplicate `permissions` after populate through filtering the user result.

```
User.findById('56e7b1f74e7192381adbfdbc')
    .populate({
        path: 'user_roles',
        model: 'Role',
        populate: {
            path: 'permissions',
            model: 'Permission'         
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            //console.log(util.inspect(user, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));

            var s = new Set();
            // remove duplicate permission 
            user.user_roles.forEach(function(u){
                u.permissions.forEach(function(p) {
                    s.add(p.name);
                })
            })

            var arr = [...s]; // convert set to array
            console.log(arr);
        }
    });
```

BTW, you can nest populate the result in this way without using the module `mongoose-deep-populate`.

Comment: i didn't know about `Set()` and nest populate, i'll try it today, thank you very much...

Comment: @asedsami, `Set()` is new for ES6, which could be supported in the latest node.js version.

Comment: excuse me, why the nest populate you mentioned isn't in the mongoose documentation? i have not seen it anywhere except in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @asedsami , The populating across multiple levels in this [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can dedupe your nested array of permission using aggregation framework. You also have option of map-reduce but aggregation framework is recommended and is more performant.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$match:{_id:"56e677c1a7e7007d5cc245ef"}},
    {$unwind:"$user_roles"},
    {$unwind:"$user_roles.permissions"},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id", permissions:{$addToSet:"$user_roles.permissions.name"}}}
])
```

Based on your sample document, it should fetch

```
{ 
    "_id" : "56e677c1a7e7007d5cc245ef", 
    "permissions" : [
        "addAnswer", 
        "viewAnswer", 
        "viewQuestion", 
        "addQuestion", 
        "removeQuestion"
    ]
}
```

I'm positive you can translate it into mongoose and it's quite easy.